# Spring Boot and iReport export

Tags: spring-boot, jasper-reports

I have an application in spring boot and angularjs, where I use jQuery DataTables to view my data. My datatable has several functions like buttons, actions, other datatables (details) and I need to export to PDF and Excel. As I'm starting to work with spring boot I researched ways to do this export, I saw that one of the best tools is iReport. I tried to export the jQuery DataTable itself, but as there are details of the main datatables, it does not export correctly.
I wonder if there is any other way to export the data other than iReport. If this is the best way, how do I pass an already loaded list of data to iReport and print it?